# Hibernate 6+ Unable to map java enum to postgres enum

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

After upgrading to hibernate 6 I am having issues with postgres being able to save enum types. I am no longer able to use `@TypeDef` annotation as it was removed.

```
@Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
@Type(MyPSQLType.class)
private MyType myType;
```

The postgres type is defined as

```
public class MyPSQLType extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType<MyType> {
    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, MyType value, int index, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        st.setObject(index, value != null ? value.name() : null, Types.OTHER);
    }
}
```

This is the error I am now getting. Do I have to now register the custom type in a different way now that TypeDef is no longer applicable?

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: my_type = character varying
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 187
```

Comment: The equivalent of `@TypeDef` is `@TypeRegistration` https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/TypeRegistration.html. But that doesn't explain the error.

Comment: @GavinKing Just the CR releases are available for 6.2 it seems? The only ones available to me in my version are `@JavaTypeRegistry` & `@JdbcTypeRegistry` but, I have no idea how to use them as there appears to be zero documentation on how they are supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the hibernate 6 provided type resolved my issue

```
@Type(PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the PostgreSQL JDBC driver expects the values to be passed in, or how you did this before, but I guess you will have to use this instead:

```java
if ( value == null ) {
  st.setNull(index, Types.OTHER, "my_type");
}
else {
  PGObject object = new PGObject();
  object.setType("my_type");
  object.setValue(value.name());
  st.setObject(index, object, Types.OTHER);
}
```

Comment: Is the PGObject supposed to be something I need to create on my own? I see that hibernate 6 provides two objects called `PostgreSQLEnumType` &  `PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType` but, neither have .setType() or .setValue()

Comment: `PGObject` is a type of the JDBC driver. You didn't tell me how you did this in past Hibernate versions though, so not sure what you are exactly looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Hibernate 6.2. The simplest way to map between Java enum types and postgres enum types is to  annotate your entity attribute with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, so hibernate passes the enum value as strings, and let the database do the work of casting to the enum type by creating an implicit cast `CREATE CAST (varchar AS my_type) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;`

Edit: Another option is to register an implementation of `org.hibernate.usertype.UserType`. This seems to work in the majority of cases. Different repository types (at least in Micronaut) appear to require different converters / type mapping.